# Number of guesses to reach tuple in ordered Cartesian product

Tags: combinatorics

I have a context where I would like to guess a tuple of numbers, drawn from a list of integers with replacement. Say the tuple is $(14, 3, 6)$. I know that there are three numbers in the tuple. Assume that my ideal guessing strategy is to guess the lowest numbers first, i.e.,

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
2 2 1
2 1 2
1 2 2
2 2 2
3 1 1
1 3 1
1 1 3
3 3 1
3 1 3
1 3 3
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

And so on.

My question is, how long would it take me to guess $(14,3,6)$? What math principles can I use to approach this problem? What I think I have worked out so far this this:

With this guessing approach, the length of the Cartesian product of $1..13$ repeated 3 times will be guessed first, before any 14's are guessed. In python,

```
    base_num_guesses = len([p for p in itertools.product(range(1,14), repeat=num_words_remaining)])
```

Which is $2197$.

I'm not sure what follows though. 14 having been reached, I think that the number of guesses before the next-highest target should be accounted for first: the length of the Cartesian product of $1..5$ repeated *two* times (because 14 will be present in all of these guesses, leaving only two unfixed numbers). This is $184$

Once this has been reached, the remaining number, 3, will take another 3 guesses.

I am not sure how to account for the uncertainty in the order of these later guess-counts. The number $14$ will be injected among the numbers for each of the
$1..5$ repeated twice Cartesian-product guesses. $14$ will also be injected into different positions for the last 3 guesses. I know that $3!$ will give me the number of possible combinations for the last three numbers once they have been reached. Do I simply multiply $(184+5)*3!$   , and then add this result to $2197$?

I realize that this will be the "maximum" number of guesses for the round following reaching $14$, and that the guessing might get lucky earlier on, once $6$ is also reached, and if the order is guessed correctly earlier on also.

I am especially interested in general math combinatorics principles that I can apply to a situation like this. Thank you for any insights you can provide.

Comment: I have not understood your guessing strategy.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri The strategy is to prefer to choose the lowest numbers first, with repetition. 

Hence, start with (1,1,1), then try incrementing one of those 1's at a time, (1,2,1), (2,1,1), until single-position incrementing is exhausted, then do two position increments at a time, until exhausted, then do all three. Once all have been incremented by 1, then begin with 3's, e.g., (3,1,1),(1,3,1), (1,1,3), then (3,1,2), (3,2,1), (3,2,2), (3,2,3), (3,3,2), (3,3,3), and so on.

This guessing strategy is used because the assumption is that lower numbers are most likely.

Comment: Not yet clear to me.